# Convergence of $\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln(n) \cdot \prod_{\text{p prime} \le n} (1 - \frac{1}p)$

Tags: convergence-divergence

The expression $\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln(n) \cdot \prod_{\text{p prime} \le n} (1 - \frac{1}p)$ seems to converge to 0.5614372$\dots$

Assuming it converges to $\lambda = 0.5614372\dots$ 
does that imply $\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{\text{p prime} \le n} (1 - \frac{1}p) = \frac{\lambda}{\ln n}$ 
and therefore Euler's totient function can be expressed as: $\varphi(n) = n \cdot \prod_{\text{p prime} \le n} (1 - \frac{1}p) = \frac{\lambda n}{\ln n}$

Comment: The limit [should be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant#Exponential) $e^{-\gamma}$ (see [too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems#Third_theorem)) and no and no...

Comment: but [we have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Growth_rate) $\displaystyle\lim\inf\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}\log\log n = e^{-\gamma}$